# Number of Non negative integral solutions of $x+2y+3z+4w=12$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Find Number of positive integral solutions of $x+2y+3z+4w=12$

I tried to split the problem in to cases :

we have $2z+2y+4w$ is always  Even and $12$ is Even number.

Hence $x+z$ should be even number which implies

Case $1.$ $x$ is Even and $z$ is even

Letting $x=2p$ and $z=2q$ we get

$p+y+3q+2w=6$

Now Let $q=0$ we have

$$p+y+2w=6$$

$$p+y=6-2w$$

Number of solutions by stars and bars is given by

$$\sum_{w=0}^{3} 7-2w=16$$

Again letting $q=1$ we have to repeat same process.

This method i feel is so lengthy. Any other way?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1621008/how-many-non-negative-integer-solutions-does-the-equation-3x-y-z-24-have), or  [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999319/how-solutions-of-distinct-non-negative-solutions-are-there-to-k-1-cdotsk-n-k?rq=1) and many more on MSE.

Comment: Are you asking for non-negative solutions, or positive solutions?  Title says one, text says the other.

Answer (score 3):

Minimum of $x+2y+3z=6\Rightarrow 4w=4$ since $8+6\gt12$ then $w=1$ necessarily.

Minimum of $x+2y+4w=7\Rightarrow 3z=3$ since $7+6\gt12$ then $z=1$ necessarily.

It follows $$x+2y=12-3-4=5$$ The only solutions of this equation are $(x,y)=(1,2),(3,1)$.

Thus there are only two solutions
$$(x,y,z,w)=(1,2,1,1),(3,1,1,1)$$

Comment: Non negative integral includes $0$ right?  So you can have for instance $(x,y,z,w)\in \lbrace (0,0,0,3),(0,0,4,0),(0,6,0,0),(12,0,0,0) \rbrace$ ???

Comment: I apologize. I read the statement "$\mathbf{Find- Number- of- positive- integral -solutions}$"  and not the title. In such case there are  more solutions easy to calculate, (4,0,0,2), (8,0,0,1), (0,3,2,0), for example.       Note.-The script between the words in bold was to avoid sticking out and not to emphasize